# Calling Latebinding Subroutine in every Subroutine

Tags: vb6, late-binding

First, I would just like to state that I need to use LateBinding due my program running in different machines with different versions of excel.

I have declared a Public Sub in a module that can be called to initiate the creation of object for the excel application.

```
'Declare Public Excel Variable to Call from one place and easy manipulation
Public xlApp As Object
Public wb As Object
Public wb2 As Object
Public ws As Object
Public ws2 As Object

Public Sub InitializeExcel()
    'Create the Excel Objects
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
End Sub
```

And then in every Subroutine that I create which uses the excel application, I call **InitializeExcel** and at every end do the following:

```
On Error Resume Next
xlApp.Quit
Set xlApp = Nothing
Set wb = Nothing
Set wb2 = Nothing
Set ws = Nothing
Set ws2 = Nothing
```

My question now is this:

> Do I need to call **InitializeExcel** on every Subroutine that needs
>   the excel application or can I just call it once at the start of the
>   application?

Comment: Why do you quit excel at the end of every routine? Why not keep it open until your app exits?

Comment: @MarkJ - I honestly do not know.  When I first started coding using Excel Application, my friend who taught me how to do it had that code in every end of his routine.  I never questioned it.  But seeing as you have commented on it, does it affect if we not close it till the app exits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested a few things and had these results:

`InitializeExcel` needs to be called every time since at the end of every Subroutine as mentioned sets the **xlapp** which is the Excel Application Object to **Nothing**

If I remove the `Set xlApp = Nothing` in each subroutine, then I can "re-use" the `xlApp` as an Excel Application Object.  This however cause an issue in which the Excel Application is kept running in the background and every time I open a new Workbook, then another instance of the Excel Application runs.

So I suppose, the best way was my initial setup in which I call `InitializeExcel` and then set everything to `Nothing` at each routine the procedure was called.